# What does “recover equanimity despite some perhaps truly significant losses” mean?

Tags: meaning

In the following quote

> The angry are also scared. They may seem bullishly confident in their rage, but they smash things up out of panic. They have no faith in their own capacity to survive frustration and recover equanimity despite some perhaps truly significant losses. They lack a resilient sense of how error and damage may be repaired, borne and overcome with sufficient, love and time.

what does “recover equanimity despite some perhaps truly significant losses.” mean?

Key words in the phrase are **equanimity** which means: calmness and composure, especially in a difficult situation.
**Despite** which means without being affected by; in spite of.
**Perhaps** which is used to express uncertainty or possibility.

My understanding of the phrase is that recovery is possible despite the possibility and uncertainty of significant losses.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show that you've looked up the key words (like "equanimity") in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain.

Comment: All done. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've voted to reopen. In the meantime, I think the confusion comes from how the sentence fits together. A paraphrase might be: "They don't believe that they can get over it ["survive frustration"] and calm down ["recover equanimity"] even if what they've lost really matters." "Losses" is modified by "significant," which is modified by "truly," which is modified by "perhaps." Wow!

Comment: Oh, I see now that maybe the main confusion is around the word "perhaps." If the author had left it out, he'd be saying that "their losses are truly significant." They added "perhaps" because maybe some angry people are upset about things that are *not* truly significant. It's perhaps not great writing, to use a strengthening modifier ("truly significant"), and then dilute it with a qualifier ("Well, I mean, *perhaps*").

Comment: I think he used "perhaps" because not everyone suffered the same level of loss. Some suffered minor losses, while others suffered truly significant ones.

Comment: That makes sense .Thanks @AndyBonner